Encoding/Decoding in Spring Boot
I have a Spring Boot application (A1), and I need to invoke another application (A2) via Rest API. A1 is written in Java + Spring Boot while A2 is written in python and tornado. A1 is trying to invoke /Get that is exposed by A2. The /Get url is something like:
https:123.456:123/something?industry=Test Data O&G Upstream - NA & Europe. The A1 application is encoding the above requestParam as industry=Test+Data+O%26G+Upstream+-+NA+%26+Europe. Based on my analysis till now it & that is causing the issue.
I am using URLEncoder to encode the value.
The same request works on the postman but not with Spring Boot.

on urls when it have ? means is coming params and & is for more params like ?lan=en&country=uk . So if you want values with & as text it should be "&" -> "%26". ?lan=en&country=uk%26nl

Can you show the code that's doing the HTTP GET request?
